# Mostrar el código ascii de una palabra ingresada con for en VisualBasic

Tags: vb6, visual

ocupo ayuda con un programa de viasul basic, debe de sacar toda la palabra en ascii y solo muestra una con el ciclo for

```
 Dim chertext As Char
        Dim i As Integer = 1

    For i = 1 To Len(cadena.Text)

        ascii.Text = Mid(cadena.Text, i, 1)

        ascii.Text = ascii.Text & "   " & Asc(chertext)
        ascii.Text = Asc(ascii.Text)
        i += 1
    Next
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no se que es ascii.Text, pero lo estas usando para absolutamente todo!!!.. no deberias usar alguna variable auxiliar?

Comment: para que tenes chertext , si no lo usas? para que haces ascii.Text = Asc(ascii.Text)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim chertext As Char
Dim i As Integer = 1
For i = 1 To Len(cadena.Text)
    chertext = Mid(cadena.Text, i, 1)
    ascii.Text = ascii.Text & "   " & Asc(chertext)
    i += 1
Next
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._